# Pinescript index range

Tags: indexing, pine-script

Is there a way to code an index range in pinescript?  For example, If I want to include all close values between 10 bars and 5 bars ago.  Everything between close[10] and close[5].

In python this would be close[5:10] but I cannot find any literature discussing a range of indexes.

thanks!

Comment: [array.slice()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}slice) might be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could code a function to do that, but to be clear `[]` has a specific meaning in Pinescript as a history-referencing operator. I think what you are asking for is a way to construct an array of values from a series based on indicies.

This would work if you're use float values like OHLC

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

range(_src, _a, _b) =>
    _arr = array.new_float(0)
    for i = _a to _b - 1
        array.push(_arr, _src[i])
    _arr

someCloses = range(close, 5, 10)
plot(array.size(someCloses))
```

But with this you are converting your data to a different type. So make sure to look at the available array functions.